I would like to add a peninsula to an existing L shaped kitchen
Can I place a drop-in gas cooktop (2 burners is enough) in to the corner of the kitchen counter and then extend the counter to form the peninsula? Will I need a range hood on the above cabinet and how far does it have to be from the stovetop?

Too many unknowns. Pictures and/or diagram showing existing and planned dimensions/layout would help a lot. You will need a range hood, but it can be free-standing or attached to a cabinet. Distances will depend on: local code in use, manufacturer instructions for the cooktop, type of hood, etc.

Yes you possibly could do that.    Do you need a range hood?   Not if you have a window that opens.   Does it mean you shouldn't?   We don't know.    You need to be much much more specific.

You want to put the cook top in the corner of a counter top? You might want to rethink that for purely practical reasons. Reaching the pot/pan on the back burner might be even more difficult when reaching across the corner. Oh, is that not what you're doing? Couldn't tell without a drawing showing us what you have and what your plan is. I'm sure it's perfectly clear in your head, but my internet mind-reading skills are a bit soft these days.
